Не могу найти, как сделать вход через Microsoft
Я создаю лаунчер Майнкрафт, и хотел, чтобы в нём был вход через Microsoft, как в официальном лаунчере.
Возможно ли это?


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/
